# return alert from function

Tags: javascript

please can you tell me why this wont work.

If I call s.A why wont the alert show.

```
var s = {

    A: function () { alert("test A"); },
    B: function () { alert("test B"); }

};


s.A;
```

thanks

Comment: `s.A()`. You need the parentheses to call it, even if the argument list is empty.

Comment: In javascript a function is also a variable. Using a function without parentheses is like passing around a variable. And using it with parentheses is calling the actual function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
s.A();
```

`A` is a function. If you just say `s.A;` all you're doing is emitting the reference to what `A` is, e.g. if I whack `s.A;` into Chrome's javaScript console I get the following:[image: Chrome Screenshot]

Notice how all it did was output the function definition?

Now, if I say `s.A();' I get what you originally expected - it fires the function:

[image]

Comment: This, you need to call the function, not just reference it.

Answer (score 3):

[see it working on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sEK8b/). you'll have to add braces to `s.A` to make it a function-call.

```
s.A();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a reference to the function, but it's not being called. To do so, add the braces after `s.A`:

```
s.A();
```